# Custom Desura library locations?

Tags: steam, desura

In Steam, there's a feature called "Library Folders" (Settings -> Downloads -> Library Folders):

[image: Library Folders]

Is there an feature, program, or workaround to do this in the Desura client?

Thanks!

Comment: From the info I have gathered I don't think it is possible to have more then one Library Folders. Though a workaround I found [(link)](https://github.com/OpenRA/OpenRA/wiki/Publishing-releases-on-Desura) states that if you install the client onto a hard drive or somewhere else the games will go there. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably worth considering that Steam only got this feature relatively recently -- before then, there was a common work around in use of creating [directory symbolic links](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) inside of the *SteamApps* folder with the name of the game's directory pointing to the new location.

I'm not really familiar with desura -- but looking at it I see no reason that the same concept cannot be applied to it.